# Migrating SVN project to Git - Branches and Tags coming out completely wrong

Tags: git, svn, git-svn

My aim is to migrate my SVN stored project to Git in a one-way, one-shot migration, i.e. once it's done we use Git and dump SVN completely. To that end I'm trying to migrate the commit logs from v35.0 to latest (currently v49.0) of the application. The solution for application consists of about 20-30 projects, libraries, exes, etc...

The structure (and case) of my project in SVN is as follows:

- Branches

  - 35
  - ...
  - 49
- Tags

  - 35

    - 35.0
  - ...
  - 47

    - 47.0
    - 47.1
- Trunk

There are other folders at the same level as Branches/Tags/Trunk, e.g. FeatureBranches, but they can all be ignored.

I run the following in my SVN trunk folder to get authors formatted correctly for Git:

```
svn log -q | awk -F '|' '/^r/ {sub("^ ", "", $2); sub(" $", "", $2); print $2" = "$2" <"$2">"}' | sort -u > authors-transform.txt
```

I run the following command in Git Bash prompt in a new empty folder I created for the migration:

```
git svn init --prefix "" --no-metadata --trunk=Trunk --branches=Branches --tags=Tags https://my/svn/project/
```

[UPDATED 08/02] Then I edit the /.git/config file and remove branches line and replace the tags line with:

```
tags = Tags/35/*:refs/remotes/tags/*
tags = Tags/36/*:refs/remotes/tags/*
tags = Tags/37/*:refs/remotes/tags/*
tags = Tags/38/*:refs/remotes/tags/*
tags = Tags/39/*:refs/remotes/tags/*
tags = Tags/40/*:refs/remotes/tags/*
tags = Tags/41/*:refs/remotes/tags/*
tags = Tags/42/*:refs/remotes/tags/*
tags = Tags/43/*:refs/remotes/tags/*
tags = Tags/44/*:refs/remotes/tags/*
tags = Tags/45/*:refs/remotes/tags/*
tags = Tags/45/*:refs/remotes/tags/*
tags = Tags/46/*:refs/remotes/tags/*
tags = Tags/47/*:refs/remotes/tags/*
tags = Tags/48/*:refs/remotes/tags/*
tags = Tags/49/*:refs/remotes/tags/*
```

I then run the command:

```
git lfs install
```

I then copy into the folder a .gitattributes file containing the list of files to be tracked be Git LFS. I've made multiple attempts at this so I saved this file from a previous attempt. I'd used git lfs track commands previously. Similarly I copy in a .gitignore file and the authors-transform.txt file created by the earlier command.

Next I run:

```
git svn fetch --log-window-size=5000 -A authors-transform.txt
```

Then I go away for around 25 hours that it roughly takes and do something else, eat, sleep, more work etc..

I then run:

```
for t in $(git for-each-ref --format='%(refname:short)' refs/remotes/tags); do git tag ${t/tags\//} $t && git branch -D -r $t; done
for b in $(git for-each-ref --format='%(refname:short)' refs/remotes); do git branch $b refs/remotes/$b && git branch -D -r $b; done
for p in $(git for-each-ref --format='%(refname:short)' | grep @); do git branch -D $p; done
git branch -d trunk
```

The final command above resulted in:

> fatal: Couldn't look up commit object for HEAD

[UPDATED 08/02] I fire up SourceTree and point it at my folder and the horror unfolds. There is 1 branch called "trunk" and there are 50 tags. Only 1 of hte tags is correct - 35.0, the rest are all named after one of the solution project folders; some are almost identical except there is an @number after them, i.e. Fubar@1423, Fubar@1568

If this hadn't of all gone horribly wrong I would have run the following to complete:

```
$ git remote add origin <AzureDevOps git url>
$ git push origin --all
$ git push origin --tags
```

I'm a relative Git noob and so have been piecing things together from other colleagues and Git docs but I have to admit I have a big case of imposter syndrome and am totally lost at this point. If anybody has any ideas for commands or config I got wrong and what I should do to achieve my aim I would be most appreciative.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it turns out typos + jumping the gun were my enemy.

In my list of tags I had repeated the following line twice:

```
tags = Tags/45/*:refs/remotes/tags/*
```

After that I had the following line before the tag had been created in SVN:

```
tags = Tags/45/*:refs/remotes/tags/*
```

In order to make the tags for example, 47.0 and 47.1 appear under a collapsible 47 tag in my Git UI (SourceTree) I updated the above lines used in the config:

```
tags = Tags/47/*:refs/remotes/tags/47/*
```

The above combined with the removal of the branch lines mentioned in edit on the main question got me 90% of the way there. I ended up with a main and a tags from 35 to 49 (branch/tag where made in SVN by the time I tried again). I still got a bunch of weird tags like 47.1@343, around 150 in fact. However, since it was so close I just deleted those tags getting Git to produce a list of tags to a files and used that as the basis for a batch file that contained a bunch of "git tag -d " commands.

Answer (score 0):

I have to admit that your migration method is pretty good overall.

But this git-config section is immediately dubious to me:

```
branches = Branches/35/*:refs/remotes/*
branches = Branches/36/*:refs/remotes/*
branches = Branches/37/*:refs/remotes/*
# ...
tags = Tags/35/*:refs/remotes/tags/*
tags = Tags/36/*:refs/remotes/tags/*
tags = Tags/37/*:refs/remotes/tags/*
# ...
```

Assuming you've got an svn tree somewhat similar to this:

```
https://my/svn/project/
├── Branches
│   ├── 35
│   │   ├── Buzqx
│   │   └── Fubar
│   ├── 36
│   │   ├── Buzqx
│   │   └── Fubar
│   └── 37
│       ├── Buzqx
│       └── Fubar
...
```

... the above git-config asks to map:

- `Branches/35/Fubar` to `refs/remotes/Fubar`,
- `Branches/35/Buzqx` to `refs/remotes/Buzqx`,
- `Branches/36/Fubar` to `refs/remotes/Fubar`,
- `Branches/36/Buzqx` to `refs/remotes/Buzqx`,
- `Branches/37/Fubar` to `refs/remotes/Fubar`,
- `Branches/37/Buzqx` to `refs/remotes/Buzqx`,
- etc (tags similarly).

Which I hope you can see cannot end well. The result you get is exactly what you asked for :)

Try **redoing** the branch/tag mapping so that there's **no namespace clashing**.

Also see the last paragraph of CAVEATS in [`man git-svn`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-svn#_caveats):

> When using multiple --branches or --tags, **git svn does not automatically handle name collisions** (for example, if two branches from different paths have the same name, or if a branch and a tag have the same name). In these cases, use init to set up your Git repository then, before your first fetch, edit the $GIT_DIR/config file so that the branches and tags are associated with different name spaces. For example:
>
> ```
> branches = stable/*:refs/remotes/svn/stable/*
> branches = debug/*:refs/remotes/svn/debug/*
> ```

---

### EDIT: mapping example for tags

> Each tag folder has a sub-folder for the releases e.g. 47/47.0, 47/47.1

This would be correctly described by `tags` lines in your initial git-config, but let me just tweak it a little bit, so maybe you can better see what's going on. Suppose you use this instead:

```
tags = Tags/35/*:refs/remotes/svn-tag-*
tags = Tags/36/*:refs/remotes/svn-tag-*
tags = Tags/37/*:refs/remotes/svn-tag-*
# ...
tags = Tags/49/*:refs/remotes/svn-tag-*
```

Then, this would map SVN `Tags/47/47.1` to Git *branch¹* named `svn-tag-47.1`.
Of course, this'd map SVN `Tags/35/35.0` to Git branch named `svn-tag-35.0` too, etc.

Now, notice: your `/Branches` structure is different from `/Tags` (there're no per-version subdirs!..) But your git-config mappings are the same. **That's why you get issues.**

Try something like this instead:

```
branches = Branches/49:refs/remotes/latest
branches = Branches/48:refs/remotes/stable
branches = Branches/47:refs/remotes/lastyear-stable
# ...
branches = Branches/35:refs/remotes/pre-eol

#-- or at the very very least (NOT RECOMMENDED):
#branches = Branches/*:refs/remotes/svn-branch-*
```

---

¹ <sup>svn tags must be branches in git, because they aren't immutable like git tags are.</sup>

Comment: In SVN if I checked out, for example, \Branches\49 then I'll end up with a all the folders and files that make up the application. In the ill fated git branches I don't get a branch for each of those folders (or files).

So the question becomes how do I import all the commit logs for SVN /Branches/35 to /Branches/49. I guess I could try doing just the tags/35/* to tags/49/*. Each tag folder has a sub-folder for the releases e.g. 47/47.0,  47/47.1

Comment: @Peter hmm... it just became unclear to me what result do you expect. Mind that [Git branches](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Branching-Basic-Branching-and-Merging) work a great deal differently than SVN branches! Why do you want *a branch for each of those folders* ? No. In git, "checking out a branch" applies to the **whole repo at once**. There's never a split-branching situation like "subdir `Foo` is on branch 35, but subdir `Buzz` in on branch 42" which is possible, and common, in svn. You always have sharply defined single branch for the entirety of a git repo.

Comment: What I suggest you should expect to get in git: a "master" branch (name it whatever you like: `mainline`, `develop`, `trunk`, anything goes) where new code is developed, "latest" versions are built & tested from. Maybe this is `Branches/49` in your case. Then, one often needs branches for "legacy support lines" where important bugfixes are backported to older-but-still-supported versions of your application. Maybe those are `Branches/48` back to `Branches/35` in your case, I'm not sure.

Comment: @Peter in case if SVN is the only VCS where you get the concept of a "branch" from — I'd strongly suggest revising that concept. [**git-flow**](https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/comparing-workflows/gitflow-workflow) is a good starting point. Because compared to other source-control systems, it is quite a stretch to call "svn branches" *branches* — they really aren't, they're just *CoW copies* deduplicated by the svn server. This is very different from what everyone else calls a branch.

Comment: Finally, @Peter, before you *import all the commit logs for SVN /Branches/35 to /Branches/49* — that's perfectly doable, but you must **decide which names they'll have in git**. Decimal numbers are not good names. That's what the lines in git-config do, they set the mapping; as an example: `/Branches/49` →`stable`, `/Branches/48` →`lastyear-stable`, ... `/Branches/35` → `pre-eol`. It's impossible for me to guess your exact workflow and your versioning needs; but one thing is certain: noone sane uses integers to name git branches (that's what version numbers and tags are for). See git-flow.

Comment: Please see EDIT and added highlights. Also, apologies for too much information: I now see you're already familiar with feature-branches, and aware of some ways in which git differs from svn.

Comment: Basically all I'm trying to end up with is "main" with all the commit history of the SVN branches/tags all the way back to v35. Although since git-svn seems to process the entire SVN repo regardless maybe it doesn't matter if all SVN commit history is included.

I'd like Git tags to match the point in time of the SVN tags. Thus when this finishes, I'd like to end up with "main" and tags named 35.0, 36.0..., 47.0., 47.1, 48.0, 49.0. After that I will create a branch from main called "development".

Comment: I've updated with [UPDATED 08/02] with my latest config file used for the last attempt. It's an improvement (I think) but the tags are still coming out wrong.

Comment: Sorry I still don't get it. How many actual branches do you have, one? I mean not the v35…v49 project copies in svn — I mean actual logical *parallel lines of development*. It sounds to me, in one interpretation, that you only have 1 `main` branch plus a bunch of historic snapshots — in that case, your desired result in git will only have 1 `main` branch (plus a bunch of tags-mapped-to-branches for the snapshots).

Comment: In Git terms we only have main + X number of feature branches. The feature branches will not be migrated. So I'm trying to end up with main and whole bunch of Tags with the SVN commit messages migrated so that we don't have to keep looking at SVN logs after the migration.